# String input in java not working

Tags: java

when i enter the password "ahmad" the code doesn't execute as it true, i don't know what is the problem

but if i define variable pass = "ahmad"
it is working very well

but i want to make the user enter the password by himself

```
public class main {

static Scanner uinput= new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {


    String pass;

    while(true){

    System.out.print("Enter the password: ");
    pass= uinput.nextLine();

    if(pass== "ahmad"){
        System.out.println("It is working");
    }

    else System.out.println("failed");

    }

}
```

here is the console result:

Enter the password: ahmad
failed
Enter the password:

Comment: replace **if(pass== "ahmad"){** with **if(pass.equals( "ahmad")){** but **if("ahmad".equals( pass)){** would be better

Answer (score 0):

when you compare Strings, you should use the `equals` method instead of `==`. That should make it work.

Best,
  Julian